# Simplify a Bunch of Handlers

Tags: ios, objective-c, handler, long-polling

Suppose we have a polling method, that consume a service and base on the response (eventType) call a handler, something like (just the idea):

```
-(void)pollData {
     [[ProjectApi sharedInstance] getEvent:^(NSDictionary *event){
          EventType type = /*Take eventType*/
          switch (type) {
               case type1:
                    [self handleType1WithResponse:event];
                    break;
               case type2:
                    [self handleType2WithResponse:event];
                    break;
               ...
               case typeN:
                    [self handleTypeNWithResponse:event];
                    break;

          }
     }];
}
```

As you can see there is a bunch of handler, is there a pattern to simplify this (or a more elegant way, one goal is to reduce the ViewController responsibility, but some of this method could interact with the controller)? (Besides delegation or creating classes by handler).

Answer (score 0):

One way: construct a string from some scalar type...

```
int type = 7;  // say it's an int
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleType%dWithResponse:", type];
```

Then construct a selector from the string:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(string);
```

Then perform the selector.  (Also wouldn't be a bad idea to test first to see if you've got the method)...

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
   [self performSelector:selector withObject:event];
}
```